# Formatting external sd card as an internal storage

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, external-sd, insufficient-memory, formatting, reformat

I'm on Samsung Galaxy On7, Android 6.0.1-Marshmallow. My phone has a small internal memory, due to which I'm thinking of converting the sd card to an internal storage facility.

I read [this article](https://fossbytes.com/android-sd-card-internal-storage-adoptable-storage/), where they've explained how Android 6.0.1 allows one to convert a sd card to an internal storage facility by formatting. They've also stated in the article as to how to rollback the formatting.

Suppose I've formatted my sd card, and moved several applications there. Now, I want to rollback the formatting. As they've written in the article, I'll have to move my apps to internal storage before I format again. But, is it possible to move apps to internal storage after moving them to the formatted sd card? That is, after formatting, will I still be shown an option of moving an app back to internal storage?

Moreover, can this method bypass the developer's setting which prevents an app to be moved to sd card? I mean, if I have an app that cannot be ordinarily moved to sd card, then after formating, will I be able to move it to sd card?

Answer (score 0):

When you format sd card as adoptable storage it will behave like internal storage you can move apps on it. But beware it will be encrypted so it can't be used with other device until you format it to external storage. Apps can be moved from internal storage to adopted storage as much as you want but if you want to format sd card to be used as external storage it is necessary to move apps and media to internal storage or they will be wiped  (because that is what formatting do it erase all data on partition you format).

Comment: That's what I'm asking: will I be able to move apps back to internal storage after moving them to the formatted sd card?

Comment: Yes, you will be able to move apps on adopted storage back and forth as long as sd card is adopted.

Comment: Couldn't you mark this question as duplicate? I marked it myself after looking at your profile, and finding the same question already asked,  and answered by you.